# Does Go guarantee constant addresses?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, specifications

Given an object *obj* is there a guarantee that

```
uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&obj))
```

will always evaluate to the same value regardless of when it is called?

Of course, Go guarantees that if you take two pointers to the same object, they will always compare equal. It might be possible though that an implementation moves an object in memory and transparently updates all pointers to it.

This is interesting if you consider garbage collection strategies like [Mark-and-Compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark-compact_algorithm). Would an implementor be allowed to use such a garbage collection strategy?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no such guarantee, exactly so that it is possible to implement a moving collector.

In fact, although the garbage collector does not move heap objects today, in Go 1.3 stacks can move when needing to grow, so it is entirely possible that

```
var obj int
fmt.Println(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&obj)))
bigFunc()
fmt.Println(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&obj)))
```

will print two different pointers, because bigFunc grew the stack, causing obj and everything else on the stack to move.

Comment: So the code in sync.copyChecker exploits undefined behavior? Is it safe to pass structures allocated from Go to C? How "long" may pointer arithmetic take to be safe from racing with the garbage collector?

Comment: 1. Yes, sync.copyChecker is using undefined behavior. The nice thing about the standard library is that it is tied to the compiler version, so it's the one place using undefined behavior is actually not a problem.

2. It works for now. We haven't figured out what we're going to do about that in the long term. I would much rather you shared C pointers between Go and C instead of sharing Go pointers.

3. Pointer arithmetic - convert to uintptr, add/subtract, convert back to unsafe.Pointer - should be done in a single statement with no function calls. I feel confident that that won't break.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything in the specification that guarantees this, probably to allow implementations of the language to use compacting garbage collectors in the future.  In [this golang-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/LwWbLL1rS-U/Uj4VRjOMtpsJ) one of the developers suggests that a compacting GC would be possible provided `unsafe.Pointer` values were pinned in memory, but this couldn't extend to all `unitptr` values.

For the current Go runtime I believe it is true, but relying on it would still be undefined behaviour.  There are a few caveats though:

1. If `obj` is a zero size type, the value of the expression may not be unique, as [described in the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).
2. Over the lifetime of a program, a particular `uintptr` value might refer to different objects.

Comment: I did answer your question.  Go (the language) does not guarantee that it is constant.

Comment: Okay.  I've strengthened the language of the first paragraph of the answer.  There is nothing in the spec that says pointers are pinned (only about how they can be compared), and that seems to be a deliberate choice.

Comment: There also isn't anything that says they aren't pinned. It might be possible that "pinned pointers" are implicitly assumed.

Comment: If the language spec assumed that pointers were pinned, then the Go developer in the mailing list thread I linked to would have said so, rather than pointing out some limited cases where pinning would be necessary.

Comment: The discussion you linked to seems to be merely a what-if scenario. They are discussing when pointers have to be pinned so it looks like the object doesn't move. From what I gather, they suggest that the moment you take an unsafe.Pointer, the underlying object is pinned and won't move anymore until the program ends. Looks like the opposite of what you read out of the thread for me.

Answer (score 3):

No absolute guarantee. Especially if Go adds compaction to its mark and sweep garbage collector.

Addresses stored in [pointer type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types)s and type [`unsafe.Pointer`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) will be updated, if necessary, by any garbage collector. Addresses stored in type [`uintptr`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) as unsigned integers will not be updated by a garbage collector. The `uintptr` type is not a pointer type, it's an integer type.

> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> `uintptr`  an unsigned integer large enough to store the uninterpreted
>   bits of a pointer value
>
> [converting unsafe.Pointers to uintptr](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/rd8XgvAmtAA/p6r28fbF1QwJ)
>
> Pointers should have been kept in unsafe.Pointers - not uintptrs -
>   always.
>
> Russ

For your example,

```
uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&obj))
```

you have an unsigned integer, not an address.

Comment: As far as I can see, the discussion you linked to is more concerned with the problem that the garbage collector may collect an object that is only referenced from an uintptr. Dave Cheney even [said](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/rd8XgvAmtAA/Z-ACvQkCi-QJ): "It is ok to convert from unsafe.Pointer to uintptr as long as the original unsafe.Pointer value is live in a stack frame." Now I am even more confused.

Comment: That fixes in that thread seem to be cases where the code was holding a `unintptr` and expecting the GC to keep the relevant allocation alive.  With precise GC where only actual pointer variables are considered, this would not be the case.