# Why Go's 4bytes aligned struct address after mod 8 is 4 in 64-bit arch?

Tags: go, 32bit-64bit, memory-alignment

When i study the code in sync.WaitGroup, 
i notice the WaitGroup use state1([3]uint32) field to assume a 64-bit aligned pointer for state atomic store.

Like this:

```golang
// https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19149
type WaitGroup struct {
    noCopy noCopy
    state1 [3]uint32
}

// state returns pointers to the state and sema fields stored within wg.state1.
func (wg *WaitGroup) state() (statep *uint64, semap *uint32) {
    if uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&wg.state1))%8 == 0 {
        return (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&wg.state1)), &wg.state1[2]
    } else {
        return (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&wg.state1[1])), &wg.state1[0]
    }
}
```

But when i check this on mac and linux,
On 64-bit system, the first alloced 4-byte aligned data structure address shows after mod 8 is **4**, while on 32-bit systems it is **0**.

I am curious how it guaranteed in golang?

code is here: https://play.golang.org/p/oiZMHd2c0I6

```golang
// 32-bit system:
// GOARCH=386 go run main.go
// 0 4 0 //why first address mod 8 is 0

// 64-bit system:
// go run main.go
// 4 0 4 //why first address mod 8 is 4
```

Updated:
With @Renat's answer address that, the variable address is not guaranteed.
The output may not be consisted.

Comment: "show 4bytes aligned address in 64-bit after mod 8 is 4, which on 32-bit arch is 0". Maybe you could explain this sentence?

Comment: @Volker Sorry for the poor explain before, i just change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [golang.org](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe) :

> Computer architectures may require memory addresses to be aligned;
>   that is, for addresses of a variable to be a **multiple of a factor, the
>   variable's type's alignment**. The function Alignof takes an expression
>   denoting a variable of any type and returns the alignment of the (type
>   of the) variable in bytes.

So given that `Alignof(c)` is `4`, it will be aligned to `4`, not necessary to `8` bytes.

When created another object of `M`

```
var c = M{}
var d = M{}
println(
    unsafe.Sizeof(c),
    unsafe.Alignof(c),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c.x))%8,
)
println(
    "    ",
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&d.x))%8,
)
```

I got:

```
12 4 4
     0
```

Comment: Your answer inspired me, i guess, 

the first alloc address of struct `M`  is an address aligned of 8, 

then add 4bytes offset, for the last 12bytes can be suit for `[3]uint32`.

So the `d` mod 8 is 0 now. 

---

And if add  `var e = MM{}` later, `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c.x))%8` will be 4 again

Does it true?

I add some code to test this situation: https://play.golang.org/p/oiZMHd2c0I6

Comment: @newbmiao , `And if add var e = MM{} later, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c.x))%8 will be 4 again` , I think it's not guaranteed. Moreover after the garbage collection, variable may change it's own address ( more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195919/does-go-guarantee-constant-addresses ), so even single variable may get `address % 8 == 4` and then `address % 8 == 0` (if it has 4 bytes alignment)